# Can I delete posts from wall with facebbok api?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

According to [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/post) an app can delete a post only if it published it. But in [this document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2) it is reported that

> *Extended Permissions give access to more sensitive information and give your app the ability to publish and delete data. All extended permissions appear on a separate screen during the login flow so a person can decide if they want to grant them.*

I don't understand if I can I delete users posts logged in with my app?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete any post made via the application you want to issue the delete request from.

Say you use Application A to post status X.
Application B cannot delete status X only Application A can.

The quoted section doesn't really contradict anything. The data it is referring to is any data that application has posted on your behalf.

Comment: Ok but can I delete users posts logged in with my app?